# How to log all events from all objects, which use Backbone.Events?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a set of objects, which use `Backbone.Events` in a standard way:

```
var object = {};
_.extend(object, Backbone.Events);
```

Also I have a third-party library, which provides a set of objects, which use `Backbone.Events`.

I would like to have a way to log all events from all of those objects, described above.

I'm aware of `all` event, but my question is wider in scope. I can create a abstract object, which logs all events and use it everywhere, but this does not work well with third-party libraries, because I have to extend it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing custom handlers for `Backbone.Layout` (from [third-party library](https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone.layoutmanager) I use), `Backbone.Model` and `Backbone` object itself.

Example:

```
// similar handler can be written for Backbone.Model
Backbone.Layout.prototype.trigger = function() {
   console.log('view', arguments);
   Backbone.Events.trigger.apply(this, arguments);
}

Backbone.on("all", function(eventName) {
   console.log(eventName, JSON.stringify(arguments));
});
```

Comment: @EmileBergeron I would love too. But it says: "you can accept your own answer tomorrow"